Application generates HTML error "Unexpected token '<'" when setting the src attribute to a js file
I'm trying to use a .js file that is set using the src attribute in a script tag in an index.html file. The application is using Node JS to launch the server and serve up this index.html file. The file does not appear to get loaded and the Edge browser debugger shows an error stating "Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token '<' (at user.js:1:1)". When I click on the error, it takes me to a the first line of the index.html and not the user.js file, showing that the error occurs at
!DOCTYPE html.
I looked for any syntax errors in the user.js file and the index.html file and it all looks good. I also changed the "type" attribute to "text/javascript" and "text/js" and also removed it to no avail.
Here is the App.js code:
const express = require('express');

const server = express()
  .use((req, res) => res.sendFile('/index.html', { root: __dirname }))
  .listen(3000, () => console.log(`Listening on ${3000}`));     

const { Server } = require('ws');

const ws_server = new Server({ server });

ws_server.on('connection', (ws) => {
  console.log('New client connected!');

  ws.on('close', () => console.log('Client has disconnected!'));
});

index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Today's Date</title>
    <script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript" src="./js/user.js"></script>    
</head> 
 
<body>
    <script>
        let user = new User('Billy');
        user.sayHi();       
    </script>        
</body>
</html>

And finally the User.js file:
class User {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  sayHi() {
    alert( this.name );
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}


Your server is serving the same HTML file when requesting the JS file, hence the error. You’re not serving the JS file anywhere.

You may need to serve the App.js file as well via .use(express.static('js'))
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
